# Reading a private authenticated image from Amazon S3 with Imagick PHP

Tags: php, amazon-s3, acl, imagick

I am fairly new to both Amazon S3 and the Imagick PHP library, but so far have been able to accomplish what I want with it (ie: uploading files and generating a range of thumbnail images). Currently, I am hung up on determining if it is possible for Imagick to read an authenticated image from S3. I would like to be able to do this in order to read back in original images for editing.

The following works when permissions for my file are set to grantee: Everyone (a public read), but not otherwise. (I've set the overall policy for my bucket to restrict access to only certain domains, including localhost where I am testing now):

```
$sourcePath = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/myBucket/folder/exampleFile-9203914980.43.jpg";
$image = new Imagick($sourcePath);
```

The above code fails to execute. Is there any setting in either S3 or Imagick that will enable the image to be read? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I now know that one answer to this dilemma is to generate a secure (signed) URL from Amazon using s3->getAuthenticatedURL($bucket, $fileName, $lifetime, true, true); I'm able to generate a URL this way. However, the URL is not fully correct as the URL returns an XML error "<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message>". Not sure what the problem could be as I've tried a lot of different things already. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to avoid having to save the image before creating the Imagick object by using the S3 Stream Wrapper:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/s3-stream-wrapper.html

```
$client->registerStreamWrapper();
$data = file_get_contents('s3://bucket/key');
$im = new Imagick();
$im->readImageBlob($data);
```

$client is the same as $s3 in Jeremy Lindblom's answer - you need to create an S3 client first as shown there.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably download the image locally before trying to work with it in Imagick. You could use the [AWS SDK for PHP](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php) to do this with some code like the following:

```
$s3 = Aws\S3\S3Client::factory(array(
    'key'    => '<your-aws-access-key-id>',
    'secret' => '<your-aws-secret-key>'
));

$bucket = 'myBucket';
$key = 'folder/exampleFile-9203914980.43.jpg';
$tempImage = '/tmp/' . $bucket . '/' . $key;

$s3->getObject(array(
    'Bucket' => $bucket,
    'Key'    => $key,
    'SaveAs' => $tempImage
));

$image = new Imagick($tempImage);

// do stuff
// ...

unlink($tempImage);
```

You can learn more about how to use the S3 client on the SDK's [user guide for S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/guide/latest/service-s3.html).

Comment: Is it really necessary to write the image to disk first?